# Stormpath not pulling in JSON markup configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, stormpath

According to Stormpath's C# [documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/csharp/product-guide/latest/configuration.html#config-reference) ([asp.net](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/configuration.html#markup-file-yaml-or-json) specifically), all one would need to do is place `stormpath.json` into the same directory as `Web.config`. However, this is not pulling in any of my configurations.

Here is where I have the file placed:

[image]

And here is an example configuration that I have:

[image]

Which would result in "Authentication required" exception as it cannot pull my config. I've verified that the credentials are correct by hardcoding them into the application. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library author here. The error messages should be improved, but "Authentication required" actually means that it **did** find some credentials to use. If it wasn't able to find any at all, you'd see "API key ID is required" instead. The "Authentication required" error means that the supplied credentials were not correct.

You should double-check that what you pasted into the JSON config file are the right credentials, but since you already did that, I'm guessing that there are some other (old?) credentials on your machine that are being picked up instead of the ones in the JSON file. Specifically, environment variables are higher in the [loading order](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/configuration.html#loading-order) than JSON config, so you might have some stray environment variables confusing things.

**Tl;dr** - the credentials are bad. Make sure the ones you want are the ones actually being loaded.

Comment: What you're saying is contradicting the documentation. From the link you posted: "values supplied via a markup file will override values supplied via environment variables for the same settings". So no matter what I have in the environment variables, my markup file should override that.

Comment: @JaredLovin You're right. I didn't notice and it's my own documentation. If that doesn't mean I need more coffee, I don't know what does. :) The documentation itself is wrong - env vars should be the second highest priority under hardcoding it in the code itself. Can you check to see if you have set those vars in the past?

Comment: Yea verily, I had old environment variables set. Once I removed them, it used the credentials in the JSON file. Please update the docs and I'll more than happily mark this as the answer! :)

Comment: @JaredLovin Documentation [updated](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/configuration.html#loading-order)! Glad you got it working.